# Use colorsys module to produce rainbow effect on Mandelbrot and Julia sets

Tags: python, colors, fractions, mandelbrot

I have some code that creates two images: two Mandelbrot sets, and one Julia set. However, I want to spice things up a bit by making them "rainbow-y" using `colorsys`.
Here is my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

imgx, imgy = 512, 512

maxIter = 256

m1 = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))
m2 = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))
j = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))

def mandelbrot(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, image, name):
    for y in range(imgy):
        cy = y * (ymax - ymin)/(imgy - 1) + ymin
        for x in range(imgx):
            cx = x * (xmax - xmin)/(imgx - 1) + xmin
            c = complex(cx, cy)
            z = 0
            for i in range(maxIter):
                if abs(z) > 2.0:
                    break
                z = z**2 + c
            r = i
            g = int((i*50)%256)
            b = int(255 - i)
            image.putpixel((x, y), (r, g, b))
    image.save(name, "PNG")

def julia(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    for y in range(imgy):
        cy = y * (ymax - ymin)/(imgy - 1) + ymin
        for x in range(imgx):
            cx = x * (xmax - xmin)/(imgx - 1) + xmin
            c = complex(cx, cy)
            z = c
            for i in range(maxIter):
                if abs(z) > 2.0:
                    break
                z = z**2 + complex(-0.1, 0.651)
            r = i
            g = int((i*50)%256)
            b = int(255 - i)
            j.putpixel((x, y), (r, g, b))
    j.save("julia.png", "PNG")


mandelbrot(-0.55, -0.5, -0.7, -0.65, m1, "m1.png")
mandelbrot(0.37, 0.38, 0.29, 0.3, m2, "m2.png")
julia(-0.6, 0.6, -0.6, 0.6)
```

I have no clue whatsoever on how to even start. Could someone point me in the right direction? I've attached 2 pictures, one of which is an images I made and one of which is an example of what I want to make.

[Mandelbrot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMvMQ.png)
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1fva.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had some success (in C not Python) by creating an RGB array that crossfades B and G with no R, then G and R with no B, and then R and B with no G. Then use the iterations (modulus array length) to index the array. Except the M-set itself which would be black.

For a smoother result, filter the image.